# Assign function as default parameter using & operator

Tags: c++, qt, qml, function-definition

I was studying an example of setting information inside of a QML table in Qt and I don't understand what is being passed as default parameter:

```
int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override
{
    return 200;
}
```

The source of the example can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html).

My guess is that `const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()` means that the default parameter is a reference to the function `QModelIndex()`, which is an inline function. Is this correct? Can someone explain to me what is happening here, please?

Comment: Default-constructed `QModelIndex` object.

Comment: If you are wondering why you would do this when it is unused, it is to conform to some abstract interface. QModelIndex is a type, so QModelIndex() must be a default constructed QModelIndex object, and `const&` arguments can bind to rvalues.

Comment: Since `QModelIndex` is a type, `QModelIndex()` creates an object of that type using its default constructor. *If* `QModelIndex` were a function, `QModelIndex()` would not refer to the function but to the result of calling it.

Comment: Thank you guys, I now understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments:

```
int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override
```

defines the overridden member function `rowCount`, its one unnamed argument has a default value of `QModelIndex()`. For any type `T`, `T::T()` defines its default constructor, so `QModelIndex()` is a default constructed `QModelIndex` object. This pattern of defining an unnamed member function argument is common practise when deriving from an abstract interface where the overriding implementation has no use for the argument.

Comment: I accept this, it is well explained and expands the comments.